# Connection to the remote SMTP host

Tags: sql-server, windows, smtp

Make the story short: Couple of the days one of the drivers in the raid started failing. After we changed the driver and rebuild it, we were not able to start SQL server. Therefore we re-installed it and restored all our DBs from backups.

Now, before hard drive crash and before the SQL was re-installed all our custom programs on the Win 2008 R2 server were able to connect to the remote SMTP host (like smtp.gmail.com) and send emails. We also used SQL database Mail and we reconfigured it, however we still receiving massages like "could not connect to mail server".

Is it possible that during SQL Uninstall some of windows services was stopped and now it cannot connect to a remote SMTP host. Where should I look and what should I try?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found my error. In the process of the server restoring I set wrong IP on one NIC and DNS was not reachable...